# Defining iterative block helpers in Meteor 0.8

Tags: meteor, spacebars

Until version 0.8 it was possible to use the regular Handlebars way for defining iterative block helpers such as the popular `each_with_key`, defined, e.g., [here](https://gist.github.com/strathmeyer/1371586) as follows:

```js
Handlebars.registerHelper("each_with_key", function(obj, fn) {
    var context,
        buffer = "",
        key,
        keyName = fn.hash.key;

    for (key in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            context = obj[key];

            if (keyName) {
                context[keyName] = key;
            }

            buffer += fn(context);
        }
    }

    return buffer;
});
```

This no longer works in 0.8, and neither [the migration guide](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Using-Blaze#new-pattern-for-defining-custom-block-helpers) nor the 
[spacebars documentation](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/spacebars/README.md#custom-block-helpers) show an example for this.

Given that block helpers are now treated like inclusions, and inclusions need to return a template (or null), instead of HTML, I'm sort of clueless as to whether and how this is even possible at this point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And just as I was about to give up, I figure it out. It's in fact easier and prettier now in 0.8 than it was before. The following seems to work great:

JS:

```js
UI.registerHelper('addKeys', function (all) {
    return _.map(all, function(i, k) {
        return {key: k, value: i};
    });
});
```

HTML:

```html
{{#each addKeys obj}}
<div>
   {{key}}: {{value}}
</div>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Theres also a bit discussed on this here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/meteor-talk/LEzKhw1Y2LE/tAEcbo1l3j4J