# Pass data to a dynamic template

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

With meteor updates up to 0.8 my old code stopped working.

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('getTemplate', function(id, context) {
    return Template[id](context);
}); 

<template name="main">
    ....
    {{{getTemplate templateName context}}}
    ....
</template>

//somewhere in other template 
Template.main.context = {name:value};
```

This way I was able to render a custom template with custom data. Now I can't find the way to pass `context` to the dynamic template. With blaze both `templateName` and `context` is undefined. Any advice?

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22750022/defining-iterative-block-helpers-in-meteor-0-8

Answer (score 2):

### Meteor >= 0.8.2

You can use the `UI.dynamic` helper render a template with a context which are both specified dynamically. For more details, check out [this issue](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/2123).

### Meteor < 0.8.2

Both of these issues are addressed on [this page](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Using-Blaze) in the meteor wiki.

1. `Handlebars.registerHelper` is now `UI.registerHelper` as seen [here](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Using-Blaze#handlebars-namespace-deprecated).
2. Examples of how to dynamically render templates are shown [here](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Using-Blaze#templatefoo-is-not-a-function-and-does-not-return-a-string).

---

#### update

Actually, given the requirements, a solution doesn't seem very obvious to me. If you are willing to use session variables to set the template name and context, AND only have one dynamic template in your main template. You could do something like this:

```html
<body>
  {{> main}}
</body>

<template name="main">
  {{> getTemplate context}}
</template>

<template name="dogs">
  <p>There are {{animals}} dogs!</p>
</template>

<template name="cats">
  <p>There are {{animals}} cats!</p>
</template>
```

```js
Session.setDefault('templateName', 'dogs');
Session.setDefault('templateContext', {animals: 10});

Template.main.getTemplate = function() {
  return Template[Session.get('templateName')];
};

Template.main.context = function() {
  return Session.get('templateContext');
};
```

Comment: Of course i've read it before ask the question. It doesn't help.

Comment: Yeah this is more difficult than I thought. I updated the answer with an example that uses session variables. This may not be what you are looking for, since it isn't very reusable.

Comment: @Serge In meteor 0.8.2 there is a new helper called `UI.dynamic` which may help solve your problem. I updated the answer with a link to the details.

Answer (score 1):

This was brought up on the meteor-core list and [@dgreensp](https://github.com/dgreensp), MDG core dev working on Blaze, opened [Ticket #2007 - How to render a template to HTML with data](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/2007) so they definitely know about this and I'd expect a fix to land soon after 0.8.0.

He also included the following workaround:

```
var toHTMLWithData = function (kind, data) {
  return UI.toHTML(kind.extend({data: function () { return data; }}));
};
```

The github ticket has further discussion and alternate code snippets that you may find useful.