# Meteorjs Template.foo() is not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, meteor-blaze

I am trying the render the template through my js like below

```
Template.customerclaim({data:""});
```

It was working fine in previous version of meteorjs with the new update it is throwing error 
`Property 'customerclaim' of object #<Object> is not a function`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### If you want to render the result

Have a careful read of [this section](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Using-Blaze#templatefoo-is-not-a-function-and-does-not-return-a-string) of the using blaze wiki. In short, what you are doing is no longer allowed so you need to use one of the example workarounds. Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22928333/pass-data-to-a-dynamic-template) related question.

#### If you want to return a string (e.g. for email templates)

Have a look at [this issue](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/2007). Specifically you can use this:

```
var toHTMLWithData = function (kind, data) {
  return UI.toHTML(kind.extend({data: function () { return data; }}));
};
```

To get a string, you can use it like:

```
var email = toHTMLWithData(Template.customerclaim, {name: 'John Doe'});
```

I'd recommend watching that issue for changes since this may not work in future versions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer david, But my concern here is how can i render a template html using javascript just like Template.foo() , Because I am generating a mail template using a template name called cusomerClaim It requires a context data to. If possible can you just give me a couple of lines ex to do this.

Comment: Oh I assumed you were trying to render the result, rather than to get a string. I updated the answer with suggestions for both cases.

Comment: I think the kind variable should be the instance of template  :P, correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Oops! You are right - you need to pass the template instance, not the name. I corrected the example.