# How do I iterate over an unknown object in a Meteor Spacebars template?

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, spacebars

So I have a Meteor Collection. Each object/document in that collection can have an unknown structure. That is to say, I don't know the name of each property, nor how many there are, until runtime.

Essentially, each object in the collection is created from arbitrary data people provide via my front-end page (via CSV upload, which works fine). So I don't initialize the collection when Meteor starts.

---

Now I'd like to create a table in my HTML page, that renders the collection, but without me pre-defining how many columns are needed and what their names are.

So how do I set the number and names of the columns in my Spacebars/HTML template dynamically?

So here's how far I've got on the template side:

```
<table>
    {{#each rows}}
      {{> row}}
    {{/each}}
</table>
```

...and the template:

```
<template name="row">
    {{#if header}}  <!-- header is explicitly set, so this is fine -->
      <th>
        {{#each WHAT?}}
          <td>{{???}}</td>
        {{/each}}
      </th>
    {{else}}
      <tr>
        {{#each WHAT?}}
          <td>{{???}}</td>
        {{/each}}
      </tr>
    {{/if}}
</template>
```

I tried finding any reference in Spacebars and Blaze documentation, but all examples always require me to know the names of the columns from the get-go.

Any ideas?

Edit:
Here's an example object, which I am explicitly identifying as the header via the header property:

[image]

...and "rows" look like this:

[image]

So I lied apparently, in that my property/column names are always index numbers.

To answer another question:
Once the data set is determined (the collection populated), all objects have the same number of properties (i.e. imagine a csv table, which is where my data will always come from).

Comment: You are correct in saying you must know the data structure to use each with data context. You can, of course, parse beforehand to a structured array or use a helper inside your each loop (`{{#each doEach(WHAT)}}`) and the helper will return your structured array.

Comment: Does the collection data have varying fields but a flat structure? Can you show us an example doc?

Comment: I've added data examples to illustrate.

Comment: Does it have to be reactive?

Comment: It should be reactive, yes. The data will be manipulated at a later point and I'd like the table to reflect this.  However, to start with I'd be happy with a non-reactive solution. ;)

Comment: you should be able to do this with an iterative block helper, see, e.g., http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22750022/defining-iterative-block-helpers-in-meteor-0-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a mongo db data modeling pov this design can be readily improved by sticking your variable fields into arrays. i.e.

```
{ items:
  [
    "wexfr",
    "123x",
    "ewfxc",
    "rgc"
  ],
  _id: "NYz84Qhu901MPab",
  header: false,
  createdAt: "2015-04-08T19:46:24"
}
```

Then you can have templates such as:

```
{{#each row}}
  {{#each items}}
```

Comment: Seems like a relatively simple compromise. I should be able to create arrays from my columns and stick those into my docs instead.

Answer (score 1):

Since your properties have no value except for an index, it's not really a good use case for objects. If you HAD to stick with the schema (or do deeply nested updates, although I'm not sure how you could...), follow Christian's suggestion. Otherwise, I'd get the front-end to give you arrays OR convert your objects to arrays in a post-process.

`data = [['uno', 'dos', 'tres'], ['wexfd', 'foobar', 'etc.']]`

Then, you could nest the `each` helpers and access the primitives with `this`. Super clean & easy.

Comment: I can see I won't get around using arrays in some sort of way. Thanks for the suggestion!