# Iterating unknown object in Meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor, data-structures, meteor-blaze

I am having trouble displaying data much like what is described here, but my object is not conveniently labelled in numbers: [How do I iterate over an unknown object in a Meteor Spacebars template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29515497/how-do-i-iterate-over-an-unknown-object-in-a-meteor-spacebars-template)

Data maybe be nested more than once, and might differ but always end in an array.
I am open to new data structures too.

**Sample Data:**

```
{
    "Category A":
        {
            "Sub-Category1":
                {
                    "Sub-Sub-Category1": ['Value1', 'Value2']
                },
            "Sub-Category2":
                {
                    "Sub-Sub-Category2": ['Value3'],
                    "Sub-Sub-Category3": ['Value4']
                }
    },
    "Category B":
        {
            "Sub-Category1": ['Value5']
    }
}
```

Comment: Please be more specific about what you want to achieve. What have you tried already? What problems did you encounter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to need a recursive template to handle arbitrary nesting, a helper that enumerates the keys of an object, and a helper that gets the value of the parent object corresponding to a key.

html:

```
<template name="nest">
{{#if isArray}}
  {{#each this}}
    {{this}} <!-- we're assuming that array elements aren't themselves objects -->
  {{/each}}
{{#elseif isObject}}
  {{#each keys}}
    {{#with value}}
      {{> nest }}
    {{/with}}
  {{/each}}
{{else}} <!-- catch the case of a scalar key value (no array) -->
  {{this}}
{{/if}}
</template>
```

js:

```
Template.nest.helpers({
  isArray(){
    return typeof(this) === "object" && this.length && this.length > 0;
  },
  isObject(){
    return typeOf(this) === "object" && !this.length;
  },
  keys(){
    return Object.keys(this); // returns an array of strings
  },
  value(){
    return Template.parentData()[this]; // look up the hierarchy to get the parent object then select the data for the current key
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, it works! However, my data is rather large and it is taking forever to load, is there any advice on how I should trigger `nest` on click?

Comment: You need an event handler that sets the state of expand/collapse at each node. You might want to look at some kind of JSON explorer package that let's you drill down into the branches of the tree.